# Numpy Zeros and String Data Type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an 18x18 grid of Numpy Zeros and I have 1's and 2's randomly filling the board using the code below.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros(324)
p=np.random.permutation(324)
a[p[:30]]=1
a[p[30:60]]=2
a.reshape(18,18)
```

And it returns the correct numpy array. However, I want to add a random X in there so I changed the first line of the code above to look like

```
a=np.zeros(324,dtype=str)
```

However, when I run the code, all of the zeros in the array disappears. It just shows up as '_'(without the underscore). Any thoughts to be able to have strings in the array but also have zeros?

Or a better way to create an 18x18 grid that can have strings in it?

Comment: It sounds like you might be better served either picking something other than `'X'` to put there, or using lists of lists instead of NumPy arrays.

Comment: Convert your `1`'s and `2`'s to strings. `0x01` has no readable character on the ASCII table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'zero' for `dtype=str` is a blank, not `0` or even `'0'`:

```
In [1]: a = np.zeros((3,3))
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [3]: a = np.zeros((3,3),int)
In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
In [5]: a = np.zeros((3,3),bool)
In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [7]: a = np.zeros((3,3),str)
In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Often it is better to specify the string length as well, but you still get blanks:

```
In [9]: a = np.zeros((3,3),'U4')
In [10]: a
Out[10]: 
array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']],
      dtype='<U4')
```

You could convert an integer array to string, and add other string values:

```
In [11]: a = np.zeros((3,3),int)
In [12]: a[[0,1,2],[2,0,1]] = [1,2,3]
In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0]])
In [14]: A = a.astype(str)
In [15]: A
Out[15]: 
array([['0', '0', '1'],
       ['2', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '3', '0']],
      dtype='<U11')
In [16]: A[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]] = 'X'
In [17]: A
Out[17]: 
array([['X', '0', '1'],
       ['2', 'X', '0'],
       ['0', '3', 'X']],
      dtype='<U11')
```

The original `0`s turn into string `'0'`.